# All Social Plugin Comments vanish from article

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

We've had facebook comments via the social plugin implemented for some time on our website, on a per-article basis.  Occasionally, an article 'dumps' all its comments.  They still show up in the app moderation back end, but none of them permit 'Visit Website'.  They may be approved, but they no longer appear on the article page, though they will still show up on the poster's facebook if they chose to post to their wall.  This seems to happen the most on 'noisier' articles, but I suspect that to be the result of more posters meaning more people to notice the disappearance.  The article will then accept new comments normally, but all old comments seem to be permanently lost.

Obviously, changing the canonical URL for the article would cause this.  However, we've had it happen on articles I do not believe changed.  Is there anything else that can cause comments to become disassociated from the article that I could possibly correct?  Can this happen if the URL (not canonical!) changes?  For SEO purposes we have the article headlines in the URLs, but the plugin is set to a canonical url without the headline to avoid disruption if the headline is updated.  Is that enough?

Comment: I believe I found the problem here.  While we were defining a canonical URL, the canonical URL defined the fb:admins property incorrectly as according to facebook documentation as opposed to the way it's supposed to be done.  As a result, Facebook was not properly using the canonical (permanent) URLs, but rather the physical URLs, which were frequently changed by article updates.  I haven't seen this happen again since I fixed that, but it was always a sporadic problem so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of the URL for an article as a unique string identifier for the comments plugin. The URL defined should be unique (only for one page). The formatting of the URL doesn't matter. However, even the slightest change in the URL will disrupt the comments plugin because now the string is technically different. I'm not sure what else could be causing your issue.

It may help to reread the documentation on the comments plugin here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/